# What did Dr. Strange say to scare Red She-Hulk?

Tags: marvel, defenders

In issue 2 of The Defenders volume 4 (written by Matt Fraction), Red She-Hulk needed to be scared in order to revert back to her human form (Betty Ross). Dr. Strange whispers something in her ear to trigger the transformation.

[image: Scare me.]

[image: I'll turn small.]

[image: Dr. Strange whispers something.]

[image: I don't like you.]

We the readers aren't privy to what Dr. Strange whispers in Betty's ear, but she refers to him as "The Creep" for the rest of the mission.

I've read all of the first six issues of the series, and they haven't referred back to this incident yet. Do we ever find out what Dr. Strange whispered, or is this left up to our imagination?

Comment: I love this series... it and the MI13 series are little appreciated gems in the MARVEL Universe.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I'll have to check out MI13. I only picked up The Defenders because Matt Fraction wrote it. He never disappoints.

Comment: @ Bill the Lizard- Yes, Matt's done some good work. I really enjoyed his X-Men run, but Paul Cornell isn't too shabby either. His [Captain Britain and MI13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Britain_and_MI13) series was nominated for a Hugo Award in 2010.

Answer (score 6):

It's a trope. When the plot demands something be said, but nothing actually said will live up to the moment or audience expectation, it is said in a whisper, with just the character's reaction shown as a way of fulfilling that expectation.

Nothing written out will ever make this scene make sense in the context.

That said, there has been no references back to this *yet*. As any plot thread, it is left dangling and someone can always come back to it, even years later.

Comment: Perhaps a link to TV Tropes [Take Our Word for It](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeOurWordForIt) article would be in order? (With appropriate warning about the time sink that TV Tropes easily becomes.) (I found the article through the Noodle Incident article, which, as one who enjoyed Calvin & Hobbes, I remembered as a search term for a similar trope, expecting to be able to follow links to an appropriate article.)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton imho that trope needs a subtrope where its just whispers, not off-screen or any other variation.